# YoutubeData API V3 - Error 400: required parameter - part

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to fetch data from Youtube API using jQuery and Ajax GET request with the required parameter, including "part". 
The GET request is ok (code 200), however when I see the data I'm getting an error 400 "required parameter: part".
Could anyone give me some tip to overcome this issue?
This is part of my jQuery and the result of the ajax request is right below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('doc ok');

  $('#tag-search').submit(function(){

    var search_term = {
        q: "test"
    };
    search(search_term);

});

});

    function search(search_term) {
        console.log('searching ...');
        console.dir(search_term);

        var search_term = '';
        var desireSearch = $ ('#tag').val();
        var channelName = 'Iron_Maiden';

  $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?', 
            part : 'contentDetails',
            forUsername: channelName,
            key: '(My personal key)',
            dataType: 'jsonp'
    })
  .done(function(results){
            var result = results.data;
            console.log(result);

});

    }
```

And this is what I got:

```
jQuery1900617815546458587_1453343296717 (
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"message": "Required parameter: part",
"locationType": "parameter",
"location": "part"
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "Required parameter: part"
}
}
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `data: {}` in the `$.ajax` request:

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?',
        data: { 
        part : 'contentDetails',
        forUsername: channelName,
        key: '(My personal key)'
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp'
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Very good suggestion!! I just had to also change the "part" to "snippet" instead. It's working properly and I'm getting data.